# Connecting to MQ with SSL - Where to begin

Tags: c#, ssl, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to MQv8.0.0.8 from C# code. I know of the Server parameters (like: QMgrName, Host, port, channel name, cipherspec etc). But I do not know what/how many certificate files do I need? I got a java KeyStore file from the MQ Admin and I extracted: *.p7b and *.p12 out of it. Installed them to my (Win7) User Key Store.

Below is the code that I am trying, but it throws MQRC: 2538 MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE

```
        try
        {
            MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "*User";
            MQEnvironment.Channel = "XXX.XXX.TLSXXX";
            MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
            MQEnvironment.Hostname = "myhosthere";
            MQEnvironment.Port = 1122;

            MQQueueManager myMgr = new MQQueueManager("QMgrname");
            myMgr.Connect();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Any clues? Any pointer to a tutorial I can begin with.
I have read & tried: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/mq_v8_dot_net_samples_can_create_ssl_connection_in_managed_mode?lang=en
IBm supplied SimplePut.exe - does not work (i.e. Throws same error code 2538)

Comment: Find out from the MQ Admin what error shows up in the queue manager log.

Comment: Seems the following worked for me: 1- Install exact version of MQ Client 2 - Get the client keys installed and check/update the Friendly Name field. It should match ibmwebspheremq<UserName> 3 - If the server does not have a specific Default Q Mgr defained - SimplePut.exe will not work (as it doesnt take QMgr as param) - So modify its code a little.

Answer (score 0):

MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE is nothing to do with your SSL/TLS settings. It says you cannot make a TCP/IP connection to your queue manager.

Double check that you have the correct hostname and port number for the queue manager with your system administrator and check the error log on the client machine for any additional TCP/IP error codes.